# Ubuntu Mouse Cursor Invisible During Install

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, system-installation

I am installing Ubuntu LTS 18.04.4 for the very first time as a dual boot with Windows 10. I have previously installed it in VirtualBox and that went flawlessly.

The first problem I'm encountering is that the mouse is invisible.

The second is that as soon as I reach the **Installation Type** screen and I choose the **Something Else** option to setup custom partitions the installer disappears completely.

I have tried this same method through both the **Try Ubuntu** and **Install Ubuntu** options, both problems persist.

EDIT: All windows seem to become invisible once the installer disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found a solution, I just had to unplug my extra displays and then reboot. After I did this both problems were immediately fixed.